# Python: Unable to remove spaces from list

Tags: python, list, spaces

I am trying to remove white spaces from a list of strings in Python.
I have tried almost every other method, but still I am not able to remove the spaces.
Here is the list:

```
names=[': A slund\n', ': N Brenner and B Jessop and M Jones and G Macleod\n', ': C Boone\n', ': PB Evans\n', ': F Neil utitle: uThe architecture of markets}\n', ': PA Hall and D Soskice\n', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ': EBYP HIGONNET and DS LANDES and H ROSOVSKY\n', '', '', '', '', '', '', ': DS Landes\n', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ': DC North\n', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ': K Polyani\n', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Here is my code:

```
for i in names:
    if len(i)== 0:   // i==''  // len(i)<=1
    names.remove(i)
print names
```

Comment: Well, you haven't tried a *list comprehension*. And what are those `//`?

Comment: 2 problems: 1. Afaik, 0 != space, so your check doesn't do what you want. 2. You need to indent the call to remove. It's not "inside" the `if`.

Comment: You can't remove items from a list while you're iterating it, so you'll have to create a new list with a list comprehension, or a for loop.

Comment: What @Francisco said. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1207461/2385132

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension.

```
names_without_space = [name.replace(' ', '') for name in names]
print(names_without_space[:3])
# [':Aslund\n', ':NBrennerandBJessopandMJonesandGMacleod\n', ':CBoone\n']
```